# Brouwer fixed-point theorem on non-convex sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I read about the [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) in Wikipedia, and got confused about whether it holds when the domain of the function is non convex. On one hand, convexity is explicitly mentioned as a pre-condition. On the other hand, they say that it holds also for domains that are homeomorphic to a disc, and there may be such domains which are not convex (e.g. a concave quadrangle). So, what is the largest family of sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on which the BFPT holds?

Comment: your question (I believe) is discussed in detail in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323841/why-is-convexity-a-requirement-for-brouwer-fixed-points-shouldnt-no-holes-be?rq=1