# Brouwer's fixed point theorem with deformation retraction instead of retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

The standart way to prove the theorem is to assume that there are no fixed points for a function $f: D^{n} \rightarrow D^{n}$ and from that obtain a retraction $r: D^{n} \rightarrow \partial D^{n}$, which sends $x$ to the intersection of the ray $x + t(f(x) - x)$ with the boundary $\partial D^{n}$, from which we then can see the contradiction by examining the induced homomorphisms in the homology groups.

My question is: doesn't this actually give us a deformation retraction? If $t_{x}$ is $t \leq 0$, for which $||x + t_{x}(f(x) - x)|| = 1$, we can define
$$
F(x, \lambda) = \begin{cases}
(1 - \lambda) x + \lambda (x + t_{x}(f(x) - x)), & \text{if } x \in D^{n} \backslash \partial D^{n} \\
x & \text{if } x \in \partial D^{n}
\end{cases}
$$
which seems to be the required homotopy relative to $\partial D^{n}$, since $t_{x}$ is continuous as a function of $x$, so this is just a composition of continuous functions. Contradiction then is with the fact that homology is different for $D^{n}$ and $S^{n - 1}$, so we still come to the needed conclusion.

By doing a quick search before posting the question, it seems that retraction variant is more educationally useful, since idea can be used in the more general proof as seen in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323841/why-is-convexity-a-requirement-for-brouwer-fixed-points-shouldnt-no-holes-be?rq=1), but this seems to also work and I just want to check that I didn't miss something obvious here.

Comment: The condition $x + t_{x}(f(x) - x) = 1$ does not make sense.

Comment: @PaulFrost oh, yes, I meant the norm is equal to one, corrected it, thank you!

Comment: With the definition $r(x) = x + t_x(f(x) - x)$ you need $t_x \le 0$. In fact, $r(x) = x + t_x(f(x) - x) = x$ iff $t_x = 0$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Not necessarily, I think. You can choose either $t_{x} > 0$ or $t_{x} < 0$, it just fixes to which of the two solutions of $||x + t_{x}(f(x) - x)|| = 1$ you are sending $x$ in a consistent way for all $x$ so retraction is continuous.

Comment: In fact you get two intersection points: One with $t_x \le 0$ and one with $t_x \ge 1$ (for $0 < t_x < 1$ you end up in the interior of $D^n$). But if you take the positive value $t_x$, you will not get a retraction. For each $x  \in S^{n-1}$ you want to have $r(x) = x$ and this is true iff $t_x = 0$.  Thus you must not choose  $t_x > 0$. This is geometrically clear: Your ray starts at $x$ and it goes *in positive direction* through $f(x) \ne x$ . Thus the map $r$ will never keep $x$ fixed if you  insist on $t_x > 0$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Oh right, I see it now, was too concentrated on what happens to points in the interiour fo $D^{n}$, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take the ray $\bar f_x$ starting at $f(x)$ and going through $x$ which has parameterization $\bar f_x(t) = f(x) + t(x - f(x))$ with $t \ge 0$. There exists a unique $\tau(x) \ge 1$ such that $\lVert \bar f_x(\tau(x)) \rVert = 1$. The function $\tau : D^n \to \mathbb R$ turns out to be *continuous*. Clearly $\tau(x) = 1$ iff $x \in S^{n-1}$. Now we take

$$r(x) = \bar f_x(\tau(x)) = f(x) + \tau(x)(x - f(x)) .$$

Anyway, if we are *given* a retraction $r : D^n \to S^{n-1}$ (whatever its construction may be), then we can define

$$F : D^n \times I \to D^n, F(x,s) = (1-s)x + sr(x) .$$
This is well-defined because $D^n$ is convex and $x, r(x) \in D^n$. Clearly $F(x,0) = x$, $F(x,1) = r(x)$ and $F(x,t) = x$ for all $x \in S^{n-1}$. Thus $r$ is a strong deformation retraction.

Comment: So you agree that my construction is valid, it seems :)

Comment: @SergeyRusakov Yes!